# How to support iOS 7.0 using xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, xcode6.4

When I push the build to app store using XCode 6.4 and deployment target as iOS 7.0, I am getting invalid minimum os version error. I want to support 7.0 OS as well. Please let me know what needs to be done.

The error is

"ERROR itms-90098: The binary is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'armv7s' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '7.0'"

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try running your code in iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: Do you write code in Swift or ObjectiveC? If you're using Swift make sure you're not using any dynamic frameworks, as those are not supported on iOS7. Does this help you?

Comment: I am getting this error while submitting to app store.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

My iPhone 6 was selected while archiving the app. After unplugging the device and archiving, it worked.

Comment: Your scheme must have Build Active Architecture Only enabled. You should not enable that for a scheme that is used to build for release.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your build settings and add arm64, armv7 and armv7s to `VALID_ARCHS`

Comment: It is already added. Even then i am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: Is the version set in both your build settings and plist file?

Comment: Yes, I had set the archs in both plist and settings

Comment: Surely the error message implies he should _remove_ armv7s, not add it?